# how to format date in crystal report as dd-mm-yy using formula field?

Tags: c#, .net, crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2010

I use

```
ToText(Cdate({dt_vw_Rept_Attend.StartDate}),"dd-MMM-yyyy")
```

formula to formate datetime string in crystal report to display day-month-year but it doesn't work for me.

if i have datetime in my database as `7/28/2015 12:00:00 AM`

so according to function it should be `28-Jul-2015`

but i am getting this again `7/28/2015 12:00:00 AM`

I need your help to resolve this. thanks in advance.

Comment: Well, what did you get instead ? Please clarify `it doesn't work for me`.

Comment: it displays as it stored in database mm/dd/yy hh:mm:ss e-g  7/28/2015 12:00:00 AM

Comment: formula is correct its working for me.. check again

Comment: but why does it not giving me result...?

Answer (score 1):

Try below code.

```
ToText({dt_vw_Rept_Attend.StartDate}, "yyyyMM")           ==>    “201101″
ToText({dt_vw_Rept_Attend.StartDate}, "dd-MMM-yyyy")       ==>   “15-Jan-2011″
ToText({dt_vw_Rept_Attend.StartDate}, "dd MMM yyyy")       ==>  “15 Jan 2011″
ToText({dt_vw_Rept_Attend.StartDate}, "MM/dd/yy")           ==>  “01/15/11″
ToText({dt_vw_Rept_Attend.StartDate}, "dddd, MMM d, yyyy") ==>  “Saturday, Jan 1, 2011″
ToText(Cdate({dt_vw_Rept_Attend.StartDate}))
```

And for more information 
http://crystaltricks.com/wordpress/?p=149
Hope you solve

Comment: i did this , but not displaying any more

Comment: Check with last one. This one works in most of case.

Comment: Have you getting any error? Can you post screen short or you can send it on bhavinvachhani403@gmail.com.

Comment: i wrote this formula on right click on detail field i-e StartDate >>Tool Tip Text>> then your mentioned code when i pressed Alt+C then system says No Error Found but at running time it does not display desired output...

Comment: okay. Don't know why it's not working. Refer this link 
http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/mahesh/DateFormatInCR06132007092248AM/DateFormatInCR.aspx

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/84469/discussion-between-tonny-and-waqas).

Comment: crystaltricks.com forces SpyWare installation - do not go there!